# How to receive encrypted payment token data of Google Pay

Tags: google-pay

I'm trying to use Google Pay on my website. Once I confirm the payment Google returns this data structure:

[image]

But I need something like this:

```
{
   "signature":"MEYCIQDTe92wpG6OUgxJ/8Qnr36XzSgjGGCM7R3LwxjgwPYMTAIhAJDrjHG9wEm1BxVM6MMMB+jGTGpi3VScEMVbHIUsObFi",
   "protocolVersion":"ECv2",
   "signedMessage":"{\"encryptedMessage\":\"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\\u003d\\u003d\",\"ephemeralPublicKey\":\"BGkK4bSvob+e7ZgaNV/4vSJYYa10OJzd3aUk9yPEP6iNBRcfHiD/NTvhKjN4P24l0tEzH3L8TrySl6AczPJpCkw\\u003d\",\"tag\":\"xGEhEfJESIyBSfq2fExWiZxNWelnm3m4i8P7cgsarqg\\u003d\"}"
}
```

Could you please advice me what should I do to get the second data structure. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response that you are after is found under `paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token`. However, the contents of this field are determined by the request parameters that you pass to `loadPaymentData`. Are you able to include the request that was used to generate the above response?

FYI, the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c012pun8/) will produce a result similar to what you are after:

```js
const tokenizationSpecification = {
  type: 'DIRECT',
  parameters: {
    'protocolVersion': 'ECv2',
    'publicKey': 'BMzk6xvwPgU8vjB...7KRu4tuRmhm6nv8=',
  }
};

/*
{
  "signature":"MEUCI...TougPg",
  "protocolVersion":"ECv2",
  "signedMessage": "{\"encryptedMessage\":\"VhQuaN...5o0Ny6Y\\u003d\"}"
}
*/
```

I achieved this by using a `DIRECT` tokenization specification which is [discouraged](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#direct):

> Key Point: The Direct integration allows merchants to decrypt the Google Pay response on their servers. To qualify, you must be Payments Card Industry (PCI) Data Security Standard (DSS) Level 1 compliant. Your servers also need to have the required infrastructure to securely handle users' payment credentials.
>
> Third parties that supply gateway or processing services on behalf of actual merchants aren't eligible to use the Direct integration. For questions about your integration as a payment service provider, contact us.
>
> If you don't meet the necessary prerequisites, we recommend that you use a supported gateway to receive a payment token.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an open issue. But here are my 2 cents and might be the answer to your solution.

***Please note***: This is an answer if you are using WorldPay/Vantiv only.

From your first response above with the token, I believe you are using gateway as "**vantiv**"

```
  "gateway": "vantiv"
  "vantiv:merchantPayPageId": "YOUR_PAY_PAGE_ID"
  "vantiv:merchantOrderId": "YOUR_ORDER_ID"
  "vantiv:merchantTransactionId": "YOUR_TRANSACTION_ID"
  "vantiv:merchantReportGroup": "*web"
```

If you want to get the second response with signature and signedMessage then all you have to do is change the gateway to "**worldpay**" and you should get the same response:

```
  "gateway": "worldpay"
  "gatewayMerchantId": "YOUR_WORLDPAY_MERCHANT_ID"
```

You can find the request [here](http://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#direct)